# Can you get the distance between your device and a bluetooth device in Cordova

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to get your device's distance from a bluetooth device using Cordova.  I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial2) plugin, but I'm not sure if I can do it with it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly. You can measure the strength of the signal and try to find your own equation/ratio to calculate distance from it. The issue is that is varies from one device to the other and is also affected by battery level of the device.

Comment: How would I do that with the given plugin

Comment: Use the readRSSI feature https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial2#readrssi